# Why com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream's method flush doesn't call output.flush() inside?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Explain me please why google coders don't call the `flush()` method?

```
  /**
  * Flushes the stream and forces any buffered bytes to be written.  This
  * does not flush the underlying OutputStream.
  */
  public void flush() throws IOException {
      if (output != null) {
          refreshBuffer();
      }
  }
```

is there any hidden reasons for this?

Comment: why should they call it? refreshBuffer seems to do the trick.

Comment: You would have to ask the authors.

Answer (score 0):

Because you might not want to flush the underlying stream.  For example, you might only want to flush the `CodedOutputStream` so that you can safely write some other data to the underlying `OutputStream` and make sure that it ends up being written after the `CodedOutputStream`'s data.  In this case you might not want to write the data out to the underlying file or socket yet, because it's more efficient to batch the data.

Comment: In that case a different method should have been provided for that purpose. FilterOutoutStream.flush() flushes the nested stream: that is the normal expectation.